# Trouble understanding de Finetti's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> A sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of $\{0, 1\}$-valued random variables is
> called exchangeable if, for any $n \ge 1$ and any $x_1, . . . , x_n ∈
> \{0, 1\}$, the probability $P(X_1 = x_1, \ldots , X_n = x_n)$ depends
> only on the ‘number of successes’ $x_1 + \ldots + x_n$ and does not
> depend on the order of $1$’s or $0$’s. Another way to say this is
> that, for any $n \ge 1$ and any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, . . . , n\}$, the distribution of $(X_{\pi(1)}, \ldots , X_{\pi}(n))$ does not
> depend on $\pi$. Then the following holds.
>
> **Theorem 8.2 (de Finetti):** There exists a distribution $F$ on $[0, 1]$ such that, for any $n \ge 1$ and any $x_1, \ldots , x_n \in \{0,
> 1\}$, $$P(X_1 = x_1, \ldots , X_n = x_n) = \int^1_0 p^k(1 − p)^{n−k}
> dF(p),$$ where $k = x_1 + \ldots + x_n$.
>
> In other words, in order to generate such an exchangeable sequence of
> $0$’s and $1$’s, we first pick $p \in [0, 1]$ from some distribution
> $F$ and then generate a sequence of i.i.d Bernoulli random variables
> with probability of success $p$.

**Questions :** What does it mean that $F$ is a distribution on $[0,1]$? Does it mean that $F$ is a CDF with range $[0,1]$ (but CDF always have range $[0,1]$ no?)

What does it mean to pick $p\in [0,1]$ from the distribution $F$? Does it mean we do [inverse sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#The_method) choosing $y\sim\mathcal{U}([0,1])$ and then compute $p=F^{-1}(y)$ or something like this?

The last paragraph

> In other words, in order to generate such an exchangeable sequence of
> $0$’s and $1$’s, we first pick $p \in [0, 1]$ from some distribution
> $F$ and then generate a sequence of i.i.d Bernoulli random variables
> with probability of success $p$.

basically means that every exchangable sequence could be generated by picking a particular $F$ and from it a particular $p$?

Comment: In short: $F$ is a CDF with *domain* $[0,1]\,.$ To pick $p$ from this distribution is to do inverse sampling as you say, and not "something like" this (that word in quotation marks should be banned from every mathematical conversation). The answer to your last question is yes.

Comment: @KurtG., but how can a CDF have domain $[0,1]$? Isn't the CDF supposed to be a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes. So let me rephrase but first consider the prime example:  If $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then its distribution is $F(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ and constant elsewhere. (Of course $F$'s range is $[0,1]$). What they mean is that their probability densities $F'$ have *support* $[0,1]\,.$ In other words: Their $p$'s can only be in $[0,1]$ since they are probabilities.

Comment: @KurtG., okay. Last thing that is bugging me : When $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are not only exchangable, but also iid, we should have $P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ right? So which $F$ to take in this case? When I consider the uniform distribution, $dF(p)=1dp$, so $P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)=\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k}dp\neq p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ right?

Comment: You are asking exactly the right questions. The $X_i$ are $\{0,1\}$ valued. Yes: When they are i.i.d. we  have that probability to be $p_0^k(1-p_0)^{n-k}\,.$ (Better to use $p_0$ as we will soon see.) The distribution you integrate over $p\in[0,1]$ that gives that single value is a delta distribution $\delta_{\{p_0\}}$ with mass at $p_0\,.$ Its distribution function $F$ is the Heaviside function that jumps from zero to one at $p_0\,.$